# Y-axis disappear when patch is see-through

Tags: matlab, plot, opacity

I'm trying to plot measurements with fitted line and predictor  bounds for several experiments to be compared and I use Matlab 2011b with Win7/64 bit.

To do so, I fit the function `FitSt`, and get the fitting data for `feval` and `predint` functions.

The problem occurs when I try to plot the predictor bounds with `patch` function and set `FaceAlpha` property to anything but 1 - the y-axis disappear. When the plot is panned, x-axis disappears as well but re-appears sometimes. When the `patch` object is deleted or the `FaceAlpha` is set to 1, the axes re-appear. Tick marks remain untouched.

When such figure is exported (using [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig)) to `pdf`, axes are visible but `patch` is opaque (I suppose `pdf` does not support opacity). When exported to `png`, the result is without axes but with opacity - exactly the same as matlab figure.

Suppose we have data in vectors `Xm`, `Ym`, `Xf`and `Yf` and 2-column martices `Xp` and `Yp`. Second characted denotes Measurement, Fit and Predictor bounds, respectively. Then not-so-minimal working example is:

```
%% Plot measurement data      / Optional
line('xdata',Xm,'ydata',Ym,'color','b','linestyle','none','marker','.')     

%% Plot fit line              / Optional
line('xdata',Xf,'ydata',Yf','color','b')

%% Plot predictor bound patch / Mandatory
pp=patch(Xp(:),Yp(:),zeros(length(Xp(:)),1),'facecolor','b','linestyle','none')

%% Plot predictor bound edges / Mandatory
Xp=[Xp;nan(1,2)];Yp=[Yp;nan(1,2)];
line('xdata',Xp(:),'ydata',Yp(:),'color','b')

%% Screw axes
set(pp,'FaceAlpha',0.125)

%% Unscrew axes
set(pp,'FaceAlpha',1)
```

Ultimate MWE:

```
fill([0;0;1;1],[0;1;1;0],[0;0;0;0],'facealpha',.5)
set(gca,'xlim',[-0.02 1.02],'ylim',[-0.02 1.02])
```

<s>What is causing this strange behaviour and</s> how can one avoid it?

Images created by whole code:
[image]
[image]

**Edit**

Same problem was discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/102250) and the problem is caused by OpenGL renderer.

When I "unscrew" the axes, te renderer switches automatically from `opengl` to `painters`. When I run `set(gcf,'renderer','opengl')`, I screw the nonscrewed axes. If I run `set(gcf,'renderer','painters')` I unscrew screwed axes but lose opacity.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with 2015b on Mac OS X

Comment: @zeeMonkeez The code is not working or it behave as expected (without any disappearing)?

Comment: I tried your 'ultimate MWE', and there's no problem with the axes display. So this may be a bug that has been fixed ... have you checked the MathWorks bug tracker?

Comment: I tried google with result: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/102250 So the problem is with OpenGL renderer...

Comment: Is it [this bug report](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/195281)?

Comment: Yes, it is this bug.